# Kentico 9 site import error

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to import a site into a new VM. This vm only has the demo corporate site.

I get an error when click Import Site or Object. The event log has two entries.

Both have the following statement: **Message: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico9\CMS\App_Data\Persistent\import_315c65f4-dc91-4175-a4e5-fdad1601727d_settings.dat' is denied.**

I check permissions in to the Kentio9 VM and they match my DEV which doesn't have this issue. I didn't set up DEV, but i can't see why my new QA VM, which seems to have the same folder permissions doesn't work.

We have a service level account for connecting to the DB, all through the application pool. Could there be something on the account settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of Identity is the Application pool are you using for this site? What about if you set it to **ApplicationPoolIdentity** and then grant permissions to **IIS_IUSRS** for your Kentico root folder?

Additionally you can try checking the [disk permissions problems](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Disk+permission+problems) documentation page.

Comment: I've been reading the docs on this. I havea temp work around by adjust the IIS permissions. It works, but it should match the other environments.

Comment: It kind of depends on network configuration of the other environments. It is possible that there are some restrictions on your production environments by default and you need to explicitely assign permissions to your IIS.

Comment: That's what i'm thinking. I'm waiting to hear from sys admins on this.